# Perdida de breackpoints en Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome

Me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación con javascript, el tema es que cuando Me vuelvo a hacer login en ella pierdo los puntos de ruptura en Chrome, cosa que antes no me pasaba.

¿Saben si hay alguna opción en Chrome para no perderlos?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Si estás desarrollando, es muy posible que hayas puesto más líneas de código, por lo que, antes querías parar el código en la línea "25" de la función "x" y ahora la función "x" se encuentra en la línea "40" y por eso no se te para.

Comment: Esto me ha pasado en otras ocasiones, pero no me refiero a eso, me refiero a que desaparecen por completo.